# symbol lookup error when running the MoveIt! GUI

Tags: ros

I am running Kubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and ROS Hydro.

When trying to complete the MoveIt! Setup Assistant Tutorial here

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_setup_assistant/html/doc/tutorial.html

everything is working fine until I try Step 4.  When I click the "Add Group" button, the MoveIt! Setup Assistant GUI closes and I get the following error:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libmoveit_setup_assistant_widgets.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 14775, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/scratch/.ros/log/a83de36e-06f4-11e4-bcc4-001fd081bf4b/moveit_setup_assistant-2.log].                             
log file: /home/scratch/.ros/log/a83de36e-06f4-11e4-bcc4-001fd081bf4b/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log                                    
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks